# Apple Feedback Service (APNS) is slow

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, feedback

I have coded Push Notifications (APNS, Apple Push Notification Service) for an iPhone App with PHP. Everything is working fine while no app is deleted from a device. I use the *Feedback Service* from Apple do get the deleted devices. If I get devices I mark them as *INACTIVE* in my database to send no further push notification to those devices.

The problem is that Apple is slow. If you delete the app from your device a request is send to Apple and I collect the devices by using the Feedback Service. But Apple is not forwarding the inactivated devices instantly so I get the following error because I can't send push notifications to a inactive device:

`PHP Warning:  fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe in apns.php on line 155`

My Feedback Service script runs every 5 minutes but the update from Apple comes every 10-15 minutes. If I send a push notification within the 10-15 minutes the above error appears because in the database the device is still marked as *ACTIVE* and on the Apple server the device is marked as *INACTIVE*.

There is no problem to connect to the Feedback Service or to the Push Service but I don't always get devices from the Feedback Service.

Greets,
TheFox

Comment: Either deal with it or contact apple support. What should we do about that?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Apple.com Developer Forum (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/114446):

*Your server needs to detect disconnections and reconnect if necessary. Nothing is "instant" when networking is involved; there's always some latency and code needs to take that into account.
Also, consider using the enhanced binary interface so you can check the return response and know why the connection was dropped. The connection can also be dropped as a result of TCP keep-alive, which is outside of Apple's control.*

So I'm gonna set all devices to *INACTIVE* if the server detects a disconnection.

Comment: I still dont really get what you're doing. Im having the same error with a few thousand push notifications. How did you fix it?

Comment: When Apple has any problem with a device they close the connection. You don't get any error message or something like that. If you get a SSL error on a device you assume that this device is not active anymore. So you must (1) turn it inactive and (2) you must reconnect to the Apple server. While you sending thousands of push notifications you maybe have hundreds of SSL errors (reconnects). I know, this system is not perfect. And I don't know why Apple has it made so tricky.

Comment: So I've managed to get the IDs which give me an SSL error. In the current situation I'm reconnecting and retrying to send the message to that ID.
Is it safe to presume that when I get a SLL error I just skip that ID en remove it from our database?

Comment: Because I also got the feedback service running which should remove all invalid ids from our database (tested and working) but its not deleting the IDS which give me an SSL error

Comment: Yes, you must manage the IDs which give you an SSL error. You must skip that ID. Don't try to resend the message to that ID. It won't work. You also must run the feedback service with a interval of 5 to 15 minutes. But the feedback service is not instant. Like the Apple Developer Forum said: _Nothing is "instant" when networking is involved_. But that's the main problem: the feedback service will be updated every (for example, I don't know the exact time) 15 minutes. So on your side you run your Feedback Service script every 15 minutes.

Comment: But within the 15 minutes, when the Feedback Service script is not running, people also can deinstall your App. So you send a pushnotification and you get an error because any user has deinstalled your app within the 15 minutes you must deal with the sending script because the Feedback Service script has no effect.

Comment: Omg.. Finally an answer that helps me a lot. Got it all figured out right now. You're a life saver.
-1 for apple and its apns service. Android does it much better btw (saying this as an pro apple user and developer)